# Matlab: How to clear persistent variable in a static method of a class

Tags: matlab

I have a class with a persistent variable in a static method. For testing purposes, I would like to clear it. The Matlab documentation for `clear` states:

> To clear a particular class, use clear myClass.

And that direction is given in [How to clear a persistent variable in a MATLAB method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13459149/3980079)

However, that hasn't worked for me. Here is a simple example of the issue. When the method is called with a single argument, that argument is assumed to be a matrix to be stored in the persistent variable. When the function is called with two arguments, those are assumed to be index references into the stored matrix.

The `class def` file, *exampleClass2.m*, located in directory *@exampleClass2*

```
classdef exampleClass2
    methods (Static=true)
        out = foo(varargin)
    end
end
```

*foo.m*, located in directory *@exampleClass2*

```
function out = foo(varargin)
    persistent persistMat;
    switch nargin
        case 1
            assert (ndims(varargin{1}) == 2)
            persistMat = varargin{1};
        case 2
            out = persistMat(varargin{1},varargin{2});
    end
end
```

and a test script

```
exampleClass2.foo(magic(5));
exampleClass2.foo(2,3)
```

> ans = 7

```
clear exampleClass2
exampleClass2.foo(2,3)
```

> ans = 7

What should I do to clear this persistent variable, and why doesn't clearing the class also clear the persistent variable?

Comment: A trivial answer to your question would be `exampleClass2.foo([])`.   :)

Answer (score 2):

**Why Clearing the Class Name Didn't Work**

The reason the usual `clear className` didn't clear the persistent variable is because the method was defined in a different .m file, as demonstrated when the method definition in included in the `class def` file.

```
classdef exampleClass3
    methods (Static=true)
        function out = foo(varargin)
            persistent persistMat;
            switch nargin
                case 1
                    assert (ndims(varargin{1}) == 2)
                    persistMat = varargin{1};
                case 2
                    out = persistMat(varargin{1},varargin{2});
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Now test it

```
exampleClass3.foo(magic(5));
exampleClass3.foo(2,3)
```

> ans = 7

```
clear exampleClass3
exampleClass3.foo(2,3)
```

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

**How to Clear When Method In Separate .m File**

To clear the persistent variable of the static method when the method is defined in a separate .m file, use `clear methodName`. For example, using the definitions from the question:

```
exampleClass2.foo(magic(5));
exampleClass2.foo(2,3)
```

> ans = 7

```
clear foo
exampleClass2.foo(2,3)
```

> Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

**What if the path includes a separate function `foo`, or other classes exist with a `foo` method?**

Unfortunately, `clear exampleClass2.foo` does not work:

```
exampleClass2.foo(magic(5))
clear exampleClass2.foo
exampleClass2.foo(2,3)
```

> ans = 7

So if the path includes a function `foo`, or other classes have a `foo` method, the persistent variables of all such functions/methods will be cleared.

Comment: If `foo` is overloaded, it exists for other classes as well or as a regular function, does `clear foo` cleat all instances of `foo`? I’m really not sure about this point. I guess it’s possible to do `clear exampleClass2.foo`.

Comment: @CrisLuengo As the call to the static method must include the name of the class (for example, `exampleClass2.foo`), and a class cannot have multiple definitions of a method, I don't think there can be any confusion from overloading. I updated the answer to address the other cases you mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for looking into that!